# Javascript - Can you use .shift() to alter an array during recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I wrote a recursive function to determine if an array contained the necessary elements to be added and form a target number. While doing so however I encountered an error while trying to remove the first element in the array using .shift() (line 8):

```
function findCombo(collection, target){
  if(target === 0){
   return true; 
  } else if(collection.length === 0){
   return false; 
  } else{
    var next = collection[0];
    //collection.shift(); **does not work**
    collection = collection.slice(1); //**works**
    return findCombo(collection, target - next) 
           || findCombo(collection, target);
  }
}
```

When I realized that collection.shift() was the problem I tried changing the array to collection.slice(1) and the program now works. Even now though I don't understand why .shift() did not apply the desired result. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Because `shift()` modifies the original collection object, so when the `findCombo(collection, target)` method is executed after the `findCombo(collection, target - next)` the collection object will be empty.

```js
function findCombo(collection, target) {
  snippet.log(target + ':' + collection)
  if (target === 0) {
    return true;
  } else if (collection.length === 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var next = collection[0];
    collection.shift(); //**does not work**
    //collection = collection.slice(1); //**works**
    return findCombo(collection, target - next) || findCombo(collection, target);
  }
}
snippet.log(findCombo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 20));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had a similar suspicion though but was confused then why the reassigning the value of the original collection variable to collection.slice(1) wouldn't also create the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have only a single `collection` array that is shared by all calls to `findCombo`, and `shift` mutates the array. This means that when the first recursive call `findCombo(collection, target - next)` empties the array, the second recursive call `findCombo(collection, target)` will find the (very same) array to be empty, altough the caller did not intend to do that. By using `slice`, the function doesn't harm the array that was given to it.

You can avoid this problem by restoring the array to its original value after the recursive calls:

```
var next = collection[0];
collection.shift();
var res = findCombo(collection, target - next) || findCombo(collection, target);
collection.unshift(next);
return res;
```

but that is a bit ugly. A better idea is to use an extra index argument for the next position to be tried, and not to mutate or clone the array at all:

```
var next = collection[try];
return findCombo(collection, target - next, try+1) || findCombo(collection, target, try+1);
```

Comment: An easy way to make these kinds of operations easier is use Facebooks Immutable.js: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: @JustGage: Indeed. Though one could argue that `.slice(1)` is already easy enough (just not as performant) :-)